# insert exclusive locking

Tags: t-sql

I have thought about the following SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO A(a1, a2)
SELECT b1, udf_SomeFunc(b1)
FROM B
```

Where udf_SomeFunc makes a select on table A. As I understand, first, a shared lock is set on A (I am talking just about table A now), then, after this lock is released, an exclusive lock is obtained to insert the data. The question is: is it possible, that another transaction will get the exclusive lock on table A, just before the current transaction takes its exclusive lok on A?

Answer (score 1):

Food for thought

```
create table test(id int)

insert test values(1)
GO
```

Now in one window run this

```
begin tran


insert into test
select * from test with (holdlock, updlock)
waitfor delay '00:00:30'
commit
```

while that is running open another connection and do this

```
begin tran

insert into test
select * from test with (holdlock, updlock)
commit
```

as you can see the second insert doesn't happen until the first transaction is complete

now take out the locking hints and observer the difference